# React-intl with a custom react components library

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

I'm having a hard time to create a react library that supports translations. Let's say I have this structure

```
components
|- Button1
    |- Button1.tsx
    |- index.ts
|- Button2
    |- Button2.tsx
    |- index.ts
lang
|- en.json
```

what I want is, when my library is imported it already has translations. The problem is I need to add IntlProvider into each component. What's more I cannot use `useIntl` hook in the same component where I use `IntlProvider`. The only possible way is to add HOC to each component. Is there's a more slick way of doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer on [github](https://github.com/formatjs/formatjs/issues/3465). Basically the whole flow should be changed by using appropriate CLI commands from format.js (extract and compile).